# Understanding the behavior of $f(x,y) = [-(1-i y)^{-x}+(-i y)^{-x}]/x$ for small $x$ and $y$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I just came across this function in my work (the integral in the first line is only to show where it came from),

\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \int_0^1 dt \frac{1}{(t-i y)^{1+x}},& x<0, y\in\mathbb{R}
\\ &= \frac{-(1-i y)^{-x}+(-i y)^{-x}}{x}, &x,y\in\mathbb{R}\,,
\end{align}

and I am really puzzled about (the real part) of its behavior near $x \sim 0$ and $y \sim 0$.  Here is what *Mathematica* shows me what the real part of the function looks like*:

[image]

It looks like it has a limit at $x=y=0$.  (It doesn't look like there's any clipping going on)

1. When I put $y = 0$ in the formula, I get $f(x,0) = -1/y$ which grows as $x\rightarrow0$ (which doesn't look like the plot).
2. When I take $x \rightarrow 0$ limit of the formula (using L'Hospital's rule), I get $f(x,y) \rightarrow \ln(1-iy) - \ln(-iy)$, which grows as $y\rightarrow0$ (closer to the behavior in plot).

I feel that there is something very sneaky about this function that I can't seem to understand.  Is the plot wrong?  Is my simple analysis wrong? and does the function have a finite limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, $y\rightarrow 0$?

---

*code:

```
Plot3D[Re@((-(1 - I y)^-x + (-I y)^-x)/x), {x, -.1, .1}, {y, -.1, .1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Re(f)"}, 
  Exclusions -> {x == 0, y == 0}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "Classic", Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: Your limit is an illusion.  Try Plot3D[Log[1/Abs[y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first term, I will use the binomial expansion up to the second order term.  The the second term, I will use the formula $a^b = \exp(b \ln a)$ and then use Taylor's series up to the second order term.  For the region you are looking at, $x \ln y$ is close to zero, except when $y$ is much smaller than $x$, and this exceptional region is probably too small for Mathematica to pick up in its graphing.

So
$$\frac{-(1-i y)^{-x}+(-i y)^{-x}}x \approx \frac{-1-i x y+\frac{x(x+1)}2 y^2 + (1-x(\ln y+i\frac\pi2) + \frac{x^2}2(\ln y+i\frac\pi2)^2)}x$$
If we take the real part of this, we get
$$\frac{x+1}2 y^2 - \ln y+ \frac{x}2((\ln y)^2-\frac{\pi^2}4) \approx  -\ln y$$

I probably got details wrong here and there, but I think the idea is sound.

I tried graphing the function in the region where $x \ln y$ is not small, but I think the value of the function changes so rapidly in that region that Mathemtica seems unable to capture it properly.  The region is about where $|y| \le e^{-1/|x|}$, and this is a very thin region indeed.

The map $y \mapsto \text{sign}(y)e^{-1/y}$ is a homeomorphism of $(0,\infty)$, so I took your expression, and made the substitution $y \to \text{sign}(y) e^{-1/y}$.  Try messing around with plots like these, and then you will get a much better idea of what happens as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

```
 Plot3D[Re@((-(1 - I Sign[y] Exp[-1/Abs[y]])^-x + (-I Sign[
      y] Exp[-1/Abs[y]])^-x)/x), {x, -.1, .1}, {y, -0.1, .1}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 2000}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Re(f)"}, 
      Exclusions -> {x == 0, y == 0}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
      PlotTheme -> "Classic", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful; especially the plot.  It looks like if $x$ is negative, then $y=0$ gives a finite real part, and grows like $1/x$ as $x\rightarrow 0^-$.  But if $x$ is positive, then the real part grows as $\sim \log(y)$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I think plots can be deceptive.  Try Plot[Exp[-1/x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1*^-10}].  No matter how you adjust the plotrange, the function will look like it spends most of the time taking the value 0, and most of the time very large.  In other words, no matter how you adjust the range on the axes, you will never get a good sense of how the function behaves.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer. I only simplify the function $f$.  Since 
\begin{align}
f(x,y)  =\frac{-(1-i y)^{-x}+(-i y)^{-x}}{x}, &x,y\in\mathbb{R}\,,
\end{align}
so that $$(1-i y)^{-x}=\left(\frac{1}{1-iy}\right)^x=\left(\frac{1}{1-iy}\cdot \frac{1+iy}{1+iy}\right)^x=\left(\frac{1+iy}{1+y^2}\right)^x$$ Similarly, $$(-iy)^x= \left(\frac{1}{iy}\cdot\frac{-iy}{-iy}\right)^x=(-i)^x\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^x$$
Therefore, $$\frac{(1+iy)^x}{(1+y^2)^x}+(-i)^x\frac{1}{y^x}=\frac{y^x(1+iy)^x}{y^x(1+y^2)^x}+ (-i)^x\frac{(1+y^2)^x}{y^x(1+y^2)^x}$$

Now, $$(-i)^x= e^{x i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)}=\cos x (-\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)+i \sin x (-\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi),\,\,\,\,\, n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Also,

$$(1+iy)^x=e^{x \log(1+iy)}=e^{x \left(\ln|1+iy|+i\arg(1+iy)\right)} =(1+y^2)^x \cdot e^{ix\arg(1+iy)};$$
where, $\arg(1+iy)=\arctan(y) + 2k\pi, \,\,\,\,\, k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So that $$(1+iy)^x=(1+y^2)^x \cdot \cos (x(\arctan(y) + 2k\pi))+i(1+y^2)^x \sin(x(\arctan(y) + 2k\pi)),$$$\forall  k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Hence, the function we have in real and imaginary parts is:

\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\frac{-(1+iy)^x}{x(1+y^2)^x}+(-i)^x\frac{1}{xy^x}&=\frac{-y^x(1+iy)^x}{xy^x(1+y^2)^x}+ (-i)^x\frac{(1+y^2)^x}{xy^x(1+y^2)^x}
\\
&= \frac{\left({1+y^2}\right)^x\cos x (-\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)-y^x(1+y^2)^x \cdot \cos (x(\arctan(y) + 2k\pi))}{xy^x(1+y^2)^x}
\\
&+i\frac{\left({1+y^2}\right)^x \sin x (-\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)
-y^x(1+y^2)^x\sin(x(\arctan(y) + 2k\pi))
}{xy^x(1+y^2)^x}
\end{align}

As $y \to 0$ with fixed $x=x_0\ne0$, then the limit d.n.e! so not like you mentioned; $f(x,0)=-1/y$ ?!